# Generating sequential number lists in tcsh

Tags: scripting, shell, csh, tcsh

I've been trying to find a workaround to defining lists of sequential numbers extensively in tcsh, ie. instead of doing:

```
i = ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 )
```

I would like to do something like this (knowing it doesn't work)

```
i = ( 1..10 )
```

This would be specially usefull in foreach loops (I know I can use while, just trying to look for an alternative).

Looking around I found this:

```
foreach $number (`seq 1 1 9`)
...
end
```

Found that [here](http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/data-services/linux_tools/linux_scripts). They say it would generate a list of number starting with 1, with increments of 1 ending in 9.

I tried it, but it didn't work. Apparently seq isn't a command. Does it exist or is this plain wrong?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there some reason why you need to stick with tcsh ? Can you use bash instead ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`seq` certainly exists, but perhaps not on *your* system since it is not in the POSIX standard. I just noticed you have two errosr in your command. Does the following work?

```
foreach number ( `seq 1 9` )
    echo $number
end
```

Notice the omission of the dollar sign and the extra backticks around the `seq` command.

If that still doesn't work you could emulate `seq` with `awk`:

```
foreach number ( `awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=9; i++) print i; exit }'` )
```

#### Update

Two more alternatives:

1. If your machine has no `seq` it might have `jot` (BSD/OSX):

   ```
   foreach number ( `jot 9` )
   ```

   I had never heard of `jot` before, but it looks like `seq` on steroids.
2. Use `bash` with built-in brace expansion:

   ```
   for number in {1..9}
   ```

Comment: Yes, I had noticed the lack of $, still didn't work. Was looking for something simple than the awk command you show, but will have it in mind for the future. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Thomas: What OS are you using? I noticed my Mac has the GNU version of `seq` installed as `gseq`, perhaps you have something similar on your system. Good luck!

Comment: @Thomas: I got it through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)'s coreutils package. But you should have `jot` available as an alternative.