# Are shell for-loops over a range different in FreeBSD vs. Linux?

Tags: shell, for-loop, freebsd

I'm trying to iterate over a range of values on FreeBSD. For example,

```
for i in {1..10000} 
   do echo $i
done
```

This works as expected on Linux, but on FreeBSD prints `{1..10000}`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`{1..10000}` is notation for [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) and characteristic of bash. Unlike in most Linuxes, [bash is not the default shell in FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-users/shells.html). Rather, [`tcsh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcsh&sektion=1) is the default. When you install FreeBSD, you are given a choice of shells. Bash is not included in the installation ISO, but can be installed later as a port. You can type `echo $SHELL` to determine what shell you are using.

Try using `seq` instead. Judging from your error, you appear to have `sh` as your shell.

In `sh`:

```
for i in `seq 10000`
```

For those using `csh` or `tcsh`:

```
foreach i (`seq 10000`)
```

If your system does not have `seq`, you can use [a workaround with `awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3921784/4497479).

Comment: There's no need to work around with awk, just use `jot`, which provides similar functionality and has been in FreeBSD for a long time. (And just to state explicitly what was implied in the answer, `seq` is in newer versions of FreeBSD.)

Comment: Also, with foreach you'll end the statement with "end", not "done".