# How to install jot command on Win10

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, git-bash

How to install **jot** command on the **Win10** because I use Git Bash to run a **xxx.sh** and show a exception as following:

```
jot: command not found
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`jot`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?jot(1))** ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3921784/6309)) is a [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) command.

So unless you can get it [sources (`usr.bin/jot/jot.c`)](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/82974662ad9f9ece5f8374d2c898e83bd03aece9/usr.bin/jot/jot.c) and somehow recompile it for mingw, I don't see it available either on Linux or as an exe on Windows.

---

Update Nov. 2020: [DimP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5951801/dimp) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435104/how-to-install-jot-command-on-win10/48436447?noredirect=1#comment114636044_48436447):

> For anyone looking for an answer on Debian etc. environments, Ubuntu has Athena-jot:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install athena-jot
> ```

Comment: This is closed now but for anyone looking for an answer on Debian etc. environments, Ubuntu has Athena-jot:
```sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install athena-jot```

Comment: @DimP Thank you for this update. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.